# Is it possible to catch a bus or train from Vietnam to places in Cambodia that are famous?

Tags: trains, buses, vietnam, cambodia

Looking to travel in Cambodia, but flights to nearby cities like Ho Chi Minh in Vietnam are about 70% cheaper right now. The only problem is that these are in Vietnam.

Is it possible to catch a bus or train to places in Cambodia that are famous (like big cities, towns, Angkor Wat)?

I am visa free in Vietnam. I have about four days. Two people.

Comment: Note that depending on what time of visa exemption you have for Vietnam,  you may not be able to reenter by land without a visa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With only four days, you are better off exploring the country where you land.  There are buses between Vietnam and Cambodia (no trains), but you will waste two of your days dealing with bus transport between the countries.  You can fly to Cambodia (Siem Reap or Phnom Penh) from Saigon or Ha Noi, saving lots of time, but costing a lot more money.

Bottom line to visit Angkor Wat with only four days you need to bite the bullet and fly to Siem Reap.